# locally hosting FB app, site url, canvas url

Tags: facebook

I have some trouble with SiteURl and canvas url, canvas page
My Appname is MySampleApp and I am trying to host it locally

So here's what I gave while creating it on FB.

```
SiteURL: http://localhost:8080/MySampleApp
Canvas URL:  http://localhost:8080/MySampleApp
Secure Canvas URL:  https://localhost:8080/MySampleApp
```

This is the error I get

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 1):

Facebook can't access a localhost, because that's - as the name says - a local DNS. If you still want to host your app locally (which is not recommended, because for this reasons there are servers on the web), you'd have to get a www DNS or just use your IP!

But again, it's not recommended unless your localhost is a proper server with (nearly) no downtime, well set security, enough capacity for a big userload,... the list goes on and on. Use a real webserver, it's cheap / sometimes for free!

It depends a bit what kind of app you are developing on FB, but here's an example:

```
SiteURL: http://yourdomain.com/page-with-app-execution.php
Canvas URL:  http://yourdomain.com/page-with-app-source.php
Secure Canvas URL:  https://yourdomain.com/page-with-app-source.php
```

The last one is for people using SSL on facebook and you only need the canvas settings when you are using the app on the facebook site itself. Your hoster can provide you with information of your real ssl-domain, its not always just adding 's' to 'http'. I can recommend [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/) if your hoster doesn't offer SSL, as Google provides SSL and webhosting for free!

Comment: Sure, there's no problem with that! You just need to find the path to your website. You should make sure though that you have a ssl domain for that site as well, which is not supported by every hoster! Afaik, Google Sites offers ssl and webhosting for free!

Comment: Could u pls explain, You should make sure though that you have a ssl domain for that site as well. I have a domain name: t*****a**.net12.net, Website:http://t*****a**.net12.net, FTP Hostname: ftp.t*****a**.net12.net. So provided all these, what should my siteurl, canvas url, secure canvas url. When u say path to the website, isn't it :http://t*****a**.net12.net

Comment: Edited my answer to give you an example! With the path to the website I just meant, that members.000webhost.com is not the right one ;) And you also need to give the full path (including the filename) to your url, so just the domain-name is not enough - UNLESS you are using your index.php for your facebook app!

Comment: I am going to use it only for debugging purposes. I was reading on the developers page facebook that for v could use localhost/8080 for hosting it locally

Comment: That's a good idea, but there are logically a few restrictions as facebook can't access a local server. Therefore it only works on iframes, but you can't really host an application, as no one else can access it.

Comment: Ok fine I am using goolge sites now. Now could u pls tell me how to create an event on this website and share it on FB wall

Comment: Create a seperate question for that, be more specific and remember this is not a discussion board! Read the FAQ!!!!!! also about upvoting and marking answers, otherwise no one will answer here anymore